# Finding width of text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, width

Is there a way to find the width of text in Javascript (jQuery is used, so happy to take advantage of any functions they provide) for a hidden element?

I want to have a graph of nodes.  Each node has text inside and I want the nodes to have a width that accommodates the text up to a limit.  So I essentially create hidden `<div>`'s with some html inside.  Then I use jQuery to display those `<div>`'s on the graph at the right spots.  It's important that I know the correct width ahead of time so I can construct the graph properly.

***UPDATE***: Just to clarify, I need to know how wide some text is while it's hidden.  Blender gave an answer below, I'm hoping there's a less tricky way?

Comment: What do you mean "width of text"? You mean how many characters in a string, or width of a control?

Comment: There's a CSS "max-width" style attribute, you know ...

Comment: (Granted, it doesn't really work in all browsers.)

Comment: Which is why I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: @at - your question really is, "Given a string of text, how do I figure out how many pixels wide it will be when rendered by the browser?" right?

Comment: @Pointy, yes that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What width do you mean? If you mean the `<div>` element's width, there's a handy function which does just what you need. Play with some of these:

```
$('#foo').width();
$('#foo').innerWidth();
$('#foo').outerWidth();
```

---

As for finding the `width` of a *hidden* element, I usually do this dirty trick:

```
var zIndex = $('#foo').css('z-index');

$('#foo').css('z-index', '-10');
$('#foo').css('position', 'absolute');
$('#foo').css('display', 'block');

var fooWidth = $('#foo').width();

$('#foo').css('display', 'none');
$('#foo').css('z-index', zIndex);
```

There must be a simpler way, though...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#txt').width()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Detect/jk97D/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style of the divs to have no wrap `white-space:nowrap` (so, text is in one line) then get the width of each div, if more than the limit, set it to the limit and set the style to allow text wrapping `white-space:normal

Comment: Who would downvote this?  It's a good answer.

Comment: Well, you can help change it :D - Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in a non-JQuery answer to this.  Assume I have a work div with id myworkerdiv and i have put my text in already.

```
var myDiv document.getElementById('myworkerdiv'),
width = myDiv.clientWidth || myDiv.scrollWidth;
```

You can also find out height as well, if your so included (clientHeight || scrollHeight).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar blender's method, but use the visibility css property rather than display. Visibility:hidden; keeps placement of the element, but just makes it invisible.